# What does struct hostent stands for?

Tags: c, network-programming, coding-style

A pointer to hostent is the struct returned by gethostbyname().

Exact function signature : `struct hostent* gethostbyname(const char*)`

And I have no idea what the 'ent' part means here at the end of hostent.

I get very forgetful when I try to memorize that I don't understand, so please help me out.

Comment: you mean _A pointer to hostent is the **value** returned by gethostbyname**2**_ : _gethostbyname_ does not return a pointer to an _hostent_ and _gethostbyname2_ does not return a struct but a pointer to

Comment: I  suppose "ent" is shorthand for "entry".

Comment: @Jabberwocky or _entity_ ? Out of that note _gethostbyname2_ is obsolete

Comment: *I get very forgetful when I try to memorize*  You don't memorize interfaces like this - because you will get them wrong.  You look them up when you need to - and that's why `man` pages exist.  When you need to use `gethostbyname()`, unless you've used it so much recently that you think you know it exactly, you either look at another usage and copy that, or read the `man gethostbyname` entry.  Because even if you do think you know it completely, you will often get compiler warnings and errors when you compile - because you **will** get it wrong many times when you don't look it up.

Comment: It means something the developer thought about but forgot to document.

Comment: Entity seem very plausible to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick [search on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22hostent%2A%20gethostbyname%22&type=Commits) points to [`basedefs/netdb.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netdb.h.html) (definitions for network database operations)

> The `<netdb.h>` header shall define the `hostent` structure that includes at least the following members:

```
char   *h_name       Official name of the host. 
char  **h_aliases    A pointer to an array of pointers to 
                     alternative host names, terminated by a 
                     null pointer. 
int     h_addrtype   Address type. 
int     h_length     The length, in bytes, of the address. 
char  **h_addr_list  A pointer to an array of pointers to network 
                     addresses (in network byte order) for the host, 
                     terminated by a null pointer.
```

From there, the [official documentation for `gethostbyaddr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html) includes:

> **Entries** shall be returned in hostent structures.
>
> The `gethostbyaddr()` function shall return an **entry** containing addresses of address family type for the host with address `addr`.
>   The `len` argument contains the length of the address pointed to by `addr`.
>   The `gethostbyaddr()` function need not be reentrant. A function that is not required to be reentrant is not required to be thread-safe.
>
> Entries shall be returned in hostent structures.
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return a pointer to a `hostent` structure if the requested **entry** was found, and a null pointer if the end of the database was reached or the requested **entry** was not found.

So there you have it: **`ent`** for **`entry`**. Not entity.

Comment: Also relevant:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netdb.h.html#tag_13_31

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree. It is relevant. Also, it is the second link in my answer.